# content outgrows div 100%

Tags: css, html, zooming

I'm currently trying to make a div that is 100% as wide as the whole screen.  And I did it by writing the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>100% width</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body {
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div style="background-color:yellow;">
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

It works fine in normal zoom settings but when I do max zoom in (FireFox 6.0.2) the letters inside the div outgrows the yellow box.  Is there a way for the yellow box to extend to the end of the window as well?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you only put the css on the div, and remove the html and body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the really long word to wrap with:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

in your div style.

Does it really matter what happens at maximum zoom though?

Comment: I guess not.  What I'm trying to achieve is something like this http://news.yahoo.com/ where even if you zoom in or zoom out to the maximum level, everything looks perfectly the same.  No element gets out of its original position.  As opposed to http://news.google.com/ where at maximum zoom the text "more" overlaps with "Sign in."  Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can be achieved with patience and experimentation..
Sorry, not much help, it really depends how your code and design works.
The reason the google one collapses onto itself is because they use some absolute position and the width of the bar shrinks to the browser width at max zoom, whereas the yahoo one scales properly with the rest of the site

Answer (score 0):

Option 1
If you want to keep the text within the yellow box try adding this CSS styling.

```
div {word-wrap: break-word;}
```

It will cause the text to go to the next line rather than continue.

Option 2
OR you could try hiding the content that goes past the div border using CSS styling

```
div {overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Seems Ben beat me to it with option 1!